# Issues in using DLL files

Tags: c#, matlab

The matlab code below  has been converted to a DLL file and it's being used in c# program in visual studio. While running the c# program it's showing an error as

> undefined variable or function name imtool, error in trail.m

`trail.m` is the name of program in matlab.But when this "trail" is runned in matlab it's showing the desired output. Can you please find out a solution.

```
if(~isdeployed)  
 cd(fileparts(which(mfilename)));         
 end    
 clc; % Clear command window.    
 clear; % Delete all variables.      
close all; % Close all figure windows except those created by imtool    
 imtool close all; % Close all figure windows created by imtool.
```

Comment: Ummm... what are you trying to accomplish here? I'm assuming that you used the Matlab-Compiler to convert the matlab code to a C# dll. That tool is designed more towards converting math logic than GUI stuff (though it can be done as well). Here, it looks like you are attempting to access the terminal window from your Matlab-code. Try changing your logic to do that from usual C# instead.

Answer (score 2):

The command `imtool` is [not supported](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html) for use with MATLAB deployment products, including MATLAB Compiler and MATLAB Builder NE for .NET. Typically, most regular MATLAB and toolbox commands are supported, but not prebuilt GUIs such as `imtool`.

However, if the use of `imtool` is within a block of code surrounded by `if (~isdeployed)`, then this shouldn't be a problem, as it will not be executed by the deployed component.

Your code snippet is incomplete, and doesn't have an `end` for the `if`. Can you confirm whether your `imtool` is within the `if (~isdeployed)` block? Or perhaps, since you're attempting to close some `imtool` windows, you have other uses of `imtool` within `trail.m`?